# html5lib installed but BeautifulSoup cannot find it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html5lib

I have installed the html5lib package. I'm sure because when i try to install it, i get a message that it is already installed.

```
pip install html5lib
Requirement already satisfied: html5lib in ./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Also i am able to successfully import that package.

```
import html5lib
```

Yet when I try to use the parser as a part of the BeautifulSoup constructor

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, 'html5lib')
```

I'm unsuccessful

```
FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Is it possible to force bs4 to lookup the installed parsers and successfully find html5lib?

Comment: I thing you want `'html.parser'` instead of `'html5lib'`. If not and you are using a smart ide like pycharm, restart it.

Comment: html5lib is what i am looking for. its different from html.parser. see the list https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: Right python versions?

Comment: @MegaIng restarting the IDE (Spyder) worked. I've previously worked successfully after installing packages and without restarting the IDE so never thought that's something I'm missing out on. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Took Megalng's suggestion and restarted the IDE. That did the trick!

Comment: Yes restarting IDE, or kernel, if you are using Jupyter notebook, should work.

Comment: Restarting was also needed for ipython.

Comment: For me it happened because the IDE auto-updated. Try restarting everything (venv, terminal, ide) ... should work.